# Recursively count through array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have the following array of data:

`id   parent_id  completed
431  NULL       0
434  431        1
435  431        1
436  431        0
437  431        1
440  431        0
441  440        1
432  NULL       0
438  432        1
433  NULL       0
439  NULL       1`

and I'm trying to write a function that I can pass an id to, that will go through the array and count all the completed values of multiple parents e.g

I pass an id of 431 and the function adds the values of completed from the following rows.

`id   parent_id  completed
431  NULL       0
434  431        1
435  431        1
436  431        0
437  431        1
440  431        0
441  440        1`

Could anyone point in the right direction to get started?

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake by answering and not just comment : Can you explicit the result you want ? Moreover, I think you should use SQL rather than PHP. // Information here was Wellso Answer : *For example if I pass the id of 431 I would return a value of 4 3 values of 1 where 431 is the parent_id 1 value of 1 from row 441 as the parent_id matches the id from row 440*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please show us what have you tried so far, and what specific problem you have?

Comment: I had a horrible bodge of a function, I'll try and recover it to show you

Answer (score 0):

```
function countArr($id, $array){   
$returnArr = array();
 foreach($array as $row){
      if($row['parent_id'] == $id){
         $returnArr[] = $row
       }
 }
return $returnArr
}
```

you will pass ID and array to search in. 
comment what else do you want to be done.

Comment: This is on the right track but I was trying to do it recursively so the function keeps calling if the id value exists in the parent_id value

Comment: so what this should return? should you remove row after it's been used or how. it's gonna loop otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it with this, just testing it out, can anyone see any pitfalls?

```
public static function calculateCompletion($content, $id)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($content as $row) {
        if ($row->id == $id) {
            if(!is_null($row->completed)){
                $count++;
            }
        }
        if ($row->parent_id == $id) {
                $count = $count + self::calculateCompletion($content, $row->id);
            }
        }
    return $count;
}
```